# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.7

Tags: python, c++, makefile, compiler-errors

I am trying to use the `Python.h` library in a c++ main file. I have installed `Python 3.7.3` in a directory `/home/zain/Desktop/MobileNet_basic/practice/Python`. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. My main file does not compile and generates an error

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.7

Please suggest me changes in my Makefile. The main.cpp file is as follows:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pDict, * pFunc, * pValue;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: exe_name python_source function_name\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();

    // Build the name object
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString(argv[1]);

    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    // pDict is a borrowed reference
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

    // pFunc is also a borrowed reference
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, argv[2]);

    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    // Clean up
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    // Finish the Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to run [Embedding Python in C/C++: Part I](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I). My Makefile is as following:

```
#Makefile

LIB = /home/zain/Desktop/MobileNet_basic/practice/Python/Include/Lib
INC = /home/zain/Desktop/MobileNet_basic/practice/Python/Include
INC2 = /home/zain/Desktop/MobileNet_basic/practice/Python/

CXX = gcc

EXE = main

SRC = main.cpp

OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -I$(INC) -I$(INC2)
LDFLAGS = -lm -L$(LIB) -lpython3.7

DEPS=$(SRC:%.cpp=%.d)

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.d $(EXE)

-include $(DEPS)
```

Comment: if I update the 'CFLAGS = -c -std=c++11 -I$(INC) -I$(INC2);' the compilation is done and main.o is generated with a warning **gcc: warning: main.o: linker input file unused because linking not done** and the main.o file does not run

Comment: And the contents of `/home/zain/Desktop/MobileNet_basic/practice/Python/Include/Lib` are what, exactly?

Comment: It is the default folder when we download python that contains the .lib files. But I am not very sure. I read it somewhere that it contains 'lpython3.7'. I can be wrong about it.

Comment: Is there something that prevents you from opening this folder, yourself, and seeing if your theory is true? And what, exactly, led you to believe that it's "the default folder", for that?

Comment: `Include/Lib` doesn't look like the right place to put libraries in.